# Input XML for WordPress' XMLRPC

Tags: xml, wordpress, xml-rpc, metaweblog

Is there any example of the XML structure for WordPress' XMLRPC service? Specifically with the `metaWeblog.newPost` method inside.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that the [Atom Publishing Protocol](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html) ("AtomPub") is a much more well-defined, well-documented, easy to use API than [Metaweblog's XMLRPC API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi). The format of AtomPub is that of the [Atom Syndication Format](http://xml.resource.org/public/rfc/html/rfc4287.html) which is very cleanly defined and has lots of implementations in many different languages.

[AtomPub has been supported in WordPress since version 2.3](http://codex.wordpress.org/AtomPub), so unless you're on an older version than that, it should just be to `POST` your `<entry>` documents to your heart's desire.